# Как синхронизировать SQLite и MySQL в Android, Kotlin?

Tags: android, mysql, json, kotlin, sqlite

Пишу приложение для Андроид на котлин.
В нём есть локальная БД SQLite. Так же есть удалённый веб сервер и в нём БД MySQL.
Необходимо сделать примерно такую логику: Если в локальной есть записи, которых нет в сетевой - то в сетевую добавляются недостающие записи. Если в сетевой есть записи, которых нет в локальной - то в локальную добавляются эти записи.

**Собственно вопрос - есть ли готовые решения или архитектурные советы по поводу реализации?**

Сам думаю сделать отдельно php скрипт для получения и записи данных в удалённую бд, и уже с приложения отправлять json на этот скрипт, а он в свою очередь будет записывать, и наоборот.

*P.S.: база будет маленькая, 1 таблица, на 30-50 записей по 6 полей. В будущем масштабироваться НЕ будет. Вся суть будет в изменениях существующих полей, и периодически добавление новых.*

Comment: Для одной таблицы можете придумать и что-то свое. Но вообще есть и готовые решения, вот к примеру https://medium.com/data-weekly/data-synchronization-with-android-d050df98db6a

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу смысла усложнять себе жизнь с отслеживанием актуального состояния в удаленной и локальной БД. Лучше напиши простенький сервер на java/kotlin/GoLang... с предоставлением API запросов к твоей удаленной БД. Так же в пользу написания своего API:

1. Что делать если у пользователя нет интернета и его локальная БД обновилась после чего он очистил данные приложения и локальная БД стала чистой :)
2. Пользователь может отключиться от интернета изменить БД как ему хочется и включить интернет, на сервер попадут не хорошие данные (не уверен)
3. Чем меньше весит приложение тем больше оно нравится пользователю

Comment: 1 - тогда пользователю подтянуться данные из сетевой БД, в этом и суть, бекап в сети на случай вайпа данных с телефона.
2 - приложение специфическое, обычных пользователей там не будет, поэтому "нехорошие" данные исключены. Удаление будет разрешено только при наличии интернета чтобы исключить забывание пользователем что он что-то удалил.
3 - данный функционал увеличит размер на 100 кБ примерно, но польза от бекапа в сети огромная!
Есть задача - связать MySQL и SQLite. Я спрашиваю о том, есть ли известные способы, чтобы не переизобретать велосипед)

Comment: 1 - У вас в вопросе написано "Если в локальной есть записи, которых нет в сетевой - то в сетевую добавляются недостающие записи.".... у пользователя нет интернета, что он скачает :)
2 - Ок
3 - Если не использовать библиотеку room, согласен бэкап полезен
MySQL и SQLite связать просто так невозможно, это совершенно разные базы данных, что бы это сделать нужно использовать JDBC драйвер
https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin/connect-to-mysql-database-from-kotlin-using-jdbc/

Answer (score 0):

Готовых решений нет. Но задача довольно тривиальная. Архитектура MVVM или MVP (на вкус) + Retrofit + RestAPI + Offline Repository SQlite.

Для начала развертываешь backend на сервере с внешним IP. (Ubnt + Apache + PHP + Mysql). Передаешь JSON из PHP (create, read, update, delet) вида: echo json_encode($response); который далее будешь передавать в Retrofit и конвертировать через библиотеку GsonConverterFactory. В phpmyadmin создаешь базу, создаешь таблицу. Делаешь Android CRUD приложение. Архитектура до безобразия простая: Rest API + Retrofit + DataModel + ResponseModel. Подключение к удаленному серверу с БД будешь получать через OkHttp. С этим понятно. Далее.

Берешь ту же архитектуру CRUD и делаешь кеширование в SQlite с библиотекой Room. Для начала делаешь модель DAO с сохранением в репозиторий SQlite. Пишешь функцию проверки линка (интернет или сервер связь) fun isOnline и fun isOffline через if else связываешь архитектуру CRUD с той или иной моделью. Проще говоря, указываешь в случае отсутствия связи интернет или связи с удаленным сервером или с БД какую модель задействовать.

Выгрузку данных из локального репозитория в удаленную MуSQL БД делаешь автоматически и асинхронно в случае появления интернета/связи с БД. И очищаешь кеш Room. Это один из путей и на мой взгляд наиболее правильный. Второй путь это синхронизация обоих БД. Что не есть гуд. Так как: а) сильно утяжелит проект, б) постоянно будет отжирать трафик юзера (так как этот самый синхронайз будет в риал тайме), и в) есть много нюансов в реализации (кода точно добавит много)

На мой взгляд лучше использовать риал тайм firebase гугловую. У нее уже встроена возможность работы с offline из коробки. Достаточно просто указать: setPersistenceEnabled(true)